# Declaring friend template class template in C++1z produces error: specialization of ‘template<class T> class A’ must appear at namespace

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17, c++-concepts

I am using boost asio coroutines and I wanted to use the new filesystem TS (-stdc++fs), so I upgraded to GCC 6-20151025 snapshot. It worked fine. But then I turned on -std=c++1z and I got an error deep in boost's source code. I isolated the error and this is a minimal example:

```
// { dg-do compile }
// { dg-options "-std=c++1z" }

template< typename T >
class A
{
};

template<>
class A< void >
{
        template< typename X >
        friend class A;
};
```

It compiles fine with -std=c++14, but generates the following error for -std=c++1z:

```
error: specialization of ‘template<class T> class A’ must appear at namespace scope
  friend class A;
               ^
```

I traced the error in the sources and it appears the behavior diverges in the newly-introduced function `maybe_new_partial_specialization' in pt.c. In particular in a condition that only activates when Concepts TS is [active](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/pt.c#L867).

I wanted to check first if this is the intended behavior in Concepts TS/C++1z before reporting it as a bug.

Thank you.

EDIT: Based on the answer(s) below, it turns out to be a bug, and I thus I have reported it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68170).

Comment: Concepts introduce two new keywords, and have no other (intended) effect on pre-concepts valid programs. So it must be a gcc bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backward compability issues were summarized in annex A of the concepts paper. It solely contains one entry:

[image]

The behavior you encountered is not intended and a regression, please report it.

Comment: Thank you. I have reported it and posted the bug URL in the question.

Comment: His code in addition is allowed currently: `class A` does not mean `class A<void>`, because "The injected-class-name of a class template or class template specialization can be used either as a template-name or a type-name wherever it is in scope. ". Here according to the previous paragraphs, it is used as a template-name, therefore not referring to a specialization, despite the error message claiming it.

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ In the source code, pt.c:868, the predicate CLASSTYPE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION is true, which according to what you are saying is the cause of the problem. I will try hunting down this and try to come up with a patch. Thank you.